# Get values from multiple entries after entry duplication

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, widget

I am working on a GUI in tkinter, and am running into a snafu when I try to use the .get() attribute to obtain values from my text entries. My GUI has a button that adds new entry boxes for the user to put in more information as you can hopefully see from the snippet below:

```
count = 1
a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
def add_line():
    global count,a,b,c,entrya
    count += 1
    Label(disframe, text="Well").grid(row=count,column=1)
    entrya=Entry(disframe,width=3).grid(row=count,column=2)
    Label(disframe, text="through").grid(row=count,column=3)
    entryb=Entry(disframe,width=3).grid(row=count,column=4)
    entryc=Entry(disframe,width=4).grid(row=count,column=5,padx=3)
    a.append(entrya)
    b.append(entryb)
    c.append(entryc)

def get_entries():
    for x in a:
       a[x]=entrya.get()
    print a

Button(root,text="Add more wells",command=add_line).grid(row=1,column=6,sticky=N)
Button(root,text="Get entry values",command=get_entries).grid(row=2,column=6,sticky=N)
```

I apologize for the messiness. I code like I engineer things: functionality first.

So if the user wants another set of three entries, he/she would click the button for them to appear. Now I run into the issue of having multiple entries with the same variable name. I have attempted to put them into an array, but that didn't work out. I think the solution might be an array of stringvar, but I'm not sure how to implement that solution. Any suggestions or questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
x=foo().bar()
```

`x` will have whatever `bar()` returns.

Thus, when you do:

```
entrya=Entry(disframe,width=3).grid(row=count,column=2)
```

... then `entrya` will have the value of `grid(...)`. This result will always be `None`.

If you want to use the object returned by a widget constructor, you need to use two steps. First, create the object and save the reference, then call grid:

```
entrya=Entry(disframe,width=3)
entrya.grid(row=count,column=2)
```

With that, your solution using an array should work fine.

Comment: Oh wow. I never would have guessed that was my problem. I'm new to Python, and especially tkinter. Thank you for telling me what was wrong in my process!

Answer (score -1):

Using only `Entry`

```
values_a = []
entries_a = []

def add_line():
    global entries_a

    ent = Entry(...)
    ent.grid(...)

    entries_a.append( ent )


def get_entries():

    for x in entries_a:
       print x.get()

# OR

def get_entries():
    global values_a

    values_a = []

    for x in entries_a:
       values_a.append( x.get() )

    print values_a
```

---

BTW: Using

```
entrya = Entry(...).grid(...)
```

you assign to `entrya` result from `grid(...)` but `grid()` always return `None`.

Use

```
entrya = Entry(...)
entrya.grid(...)
```

---

Using `StringVar`

```
strvars_a = []

values_a = []

def add_line():
    global strvars_a

    var = StringVar()

    Entry(..., textvariable=var).grid(...)

    strvars_a.append( var )


def get_entries():

    for x in strvars_a:
       print x.get()

# OR

def get_entries():
    global values_a

    values_a = []

    for x in strvars_a:
       values_a.append( x.get() )

    print values_a
```

Comment: I think your answer is very hard to understand when you start out with a bunch of lines of code that has no explanation. I'm forced to read line-by-line through the code to guess what you did differently. You might want to consider rephrasing the answer so you first describe the solution and then show the code.

Comment: Thank you for the response as well. I appreciate the code, but I want to try to get better at making my own. I obviously still need practice.